# "Invalid content entity type!" when posting to Linkedin v2/shares

Tags: linkedin-api

Followed this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares to upload images to reference in a organization share in LinkedIn.

Successfully uploaded the image using [Assets API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#upload-images-using-assets-api-recommended). The URN is in this format - `urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXX`

[Retrieving asset information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#check-status-of-upload) using the Asset ID from the digitalmediaAsset URN shows the following status:

```
{
    "serviceRelationships": [
        {
            "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent",
            "relationshipType": "OWNER"
        }
    ],
    "recipes": [
        {
            "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image",
            "status": "AVAILABLE"
        }
    ],
    "mediaTypeFamily": "STILLIMAGE",
    "created": 1579015000150,
    "lastModified": 1579015039823,
    "id": "XXX",
    "status": "ALLOWED"
}
```

But when I write a share [using Assets URN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#sample-request-using-assets-urn-recommended) -

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares

{
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entity": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXX"
            }
        ],
        "description": "content description",
        "title": "Test Share with Content"
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "subject": "Test Share Subject",
    "text": {
        "text": "Test Share!"
    },
    "owner":"urn:li:organization:YYY"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{"message":"Invalid content entity type!","status":400}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am having a similar issue that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: @Trendy, See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `shareMediaCategory` field here like this:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares

{
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entity": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXX"
            }
        ],
        "description": "content description",
        "title": "Test Share with Content",
        "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE"
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "subject": "Test Share Subject",
    "text": {
        "text": "Test Share!"
    },
    "owner":"urn:li:organization:YYY"
}
```

See the documentation for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#using-images-for-shares